# How can I change the x axis limits in the matplot function in R?

Tags: r

How can I change the x axis in the matplot function in R?

The code I've tried looks like this:

```
matplot(Data[2:7], type = c("l"), pch = 1, xlim = c(0,90,by = 5) )
```

However this returns the error
Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'xlim' value

Is there another way to change the limits on the X axis so it goes up in 5's from 0-90?

Comment: Try `xlim=c(0, 90)`.

Comment: @jay.sf I have tried this but i still return the error Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'xlim' value

Comment: You say *it goes up in 5's from 0-90*. Forget the `5` part, start the plot like @jay.sf said and with `xaxt = "n"`. Then call `?axis`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas sorry I'm new to R so i'm not sure what you mean. should I put xaxt in my code like this  matplot(Data[2:7], type = c("l"), pch = 1, xlim = c(0,90,by = 5),xaxt="5" ) ?

Comment: No!!! Put `xlim = c(0,90)` and `xaxt = "n"`, it's a letter, not a number. Then in **the next instruction** `axis(1, at = seq(0, 90, by = 5))`.